# How do you simulate a right-click in Python?

Tags: python

I cannot find this information anywhere, including its documentation - is this non existent?

doesn't matter anymore, I have found a workaround that works for now.

Comment: *doesn't matter anymore, I have found a workaround that works for now.*????

Answer (score 4):

Here's my attempt at a solution.

According to project description of [PyDirectInput](https://pypi.org/project/PyDirectInput/), this library is suppose to replicate the functionality of PyAutoGUI mouse and keyboard inputs.

In addition, this library works in conjunction with [PyAutoGUI](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

This would lead me to believe that using the [click() documentation](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html#mouse-clicks) of PyAutoGUI and replacing it with pydirectinput would result in the following solution:

```
import pyautogui
import pydirectinput

pydirectinput.click(button='right')
```

However not all optional parameters and features may be available for a particular function.

On the bright side, click() is listed among the features implemented.

There may be a chance that this parameter may not be implemented. If it's not implemented, the author Ben Johnson is open to new feature implementation. Perhaps you can work with the author to implement this parameter.

I would give this code a try.

If the code above worked and other tasks must be accomplished in PyDirectInput, I would look at the [list of features implemented](https://pypi.org/project/PyDirectInput/) (towards bottom of the page)  with the [documentation of PyAutoGUI](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). Then I would apply the same methodology used for the provided code solution to code the other tasks.

I hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
import pydirectinput
pydirectinput.rightClick()
```